# Msbuild parameter /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true is not producing a ZIP file

Tags: azure, msbuild, optional-parameters

Build environment is VSTS(Azure). Task is "Visual Studio build".
MS Build Arguments list
/m:16 /p:_DestinationType=AzureWebSite  /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"

There is one solution which contain three projects. The last Project(.csproj) should build web jobs which is why I need a .ZIP for deployment.

I included /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true but no .ZIP file is created.

What could be missing in .csproj which needed to produce a ZIP file?

No error message in build output.

Comment: is netcore / netframework ? continuous webjob ? could you add more relvant information please

Comment: It uses .net Framework 4.7 and it is a continuous webjob. What other information is required?  Do you want the .sln and .csproj files?

Comment: Did you get past this? I'm running into this after migrating from VS2017 to VS2019 build agent in Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same issue when someone accidentally removed the `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` package reference from a webjob's .csproj

As soon as we put it back, the build pipeline started generating the .zip file again.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish">
  <Version>2.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

In our case the webjob targets Import statement was still there, but that's another thing to check:

```
<Import Project="..\Dependencies\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\Dependencies\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```